# How can I dynamically move child div between parent divs using Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my sample, I have three parent divs (colored red) ... First, Second and Third.

Initially I want to put my child div (colored yellow) in the "Second" div.

After this, I want to move the child div between parent divs just by changing columnID.

Here's my test code that does not work...

```js
var dataColumns = [{
    id: 1,
    text: "First"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Second"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Third"
  }
]

var viewModel = {
  data: ko.observableArray([]),
  columns: ko.observableArray([]),
};

dataColumns.forEach(function(c) {
  let column = {
    id: c.id,
    text: c.text,
    items: ko.computed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.data(), function(d) {
        return d.columnID() === c.id;
      });
    }, this)
  };

  viewModel.columns.push(column);
});


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

let item = {
  columnID: ko.observable(2),
  caption: "I am the moving item"
};

viewModel.data.push(item);

function MoveTo(index) {
  item.columnID(index);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'columnTemplate', foreach: columns, as: 'column' }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="columnTemplate">
  <div style="background-color: red;">
    <div data-bind="text: text"></div>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'itemTemplate', foreach: column.items, as: 'item' }"></div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="itemTemplate">
  <div style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div data-bind="text: caption"></div>
  </div>
</script>

<button onclick="MoveTo(1)">Move to column 1</button>
<button onclick="MoveTo(2)">Move to column 2</button>
<button onclick="MoveTo(3)">Move to column 3</button>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/at8grkwe/3/

Is my goal impossible to do with Knockuot?

My reallife project is a kanban system, where the id of the task specify which kanban column the task should be in - and then just by changeing then tasks columnID, the task should be moved to another kanban column.

UPDATE: 
I updated snippet and Fiddle to correct the error HeyJude pointed out - but it still doesn't move between columns when clicking the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only a small mistake you've got there.

Change this:

```
viewModel.columns.push(c);
```

... into this:

```
viewModel.columns.push(column);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing that out .. but it still doesn't move between columns when I click the buttons - any idea why? Here's updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/at8grkwe/3/

Comment: Oh wait ... the snippet code here works now, but the Fiddle doesn't - going to examine that.

Comment: Well the correction works here - the fiddle doesn't, but that's ok. Thanks for helping me out :)